# Send Post request concurrently for a list of employees (No Access to API for supporting list of employees in POST body)

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, task, restsharp

```
public bool IsAllEmployeesCreated(List<Employess> employees)
        {
            return CreateAllEmployees(employees);

        }

public bool CreateAllEmployees(List<Employess> employees){
             bool isEmployeeAvailable = false;
             foreach (var employee in employees)
                {
                   

                    try
                    {
                        string connectorBaseUri = _configuration.GetSection("ConnectorBaseUri").Value;
                        Uri baseUri = new(connectorBaseUri);
                        var client = new RestClient(baseUri);
                        var request = new RestRequest("/employees", Method.POST);
                        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                        request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee));
                        var response = client.Execute(request);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                        {
                            isEmployeeAvailable = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage);
                            isEmployeeAvailable = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred while creating "+ex );
                    }
                }
                return isEmployeeAvailable;
        }
```

In the above code i made a POST call to an API which create the employee or if it is already present send Conflict so return true. Is there any way i can do the same task using Async and use Task.WhenAll() to see if all task are successful and if any of the call failed return false.

Comment: Have you considered creating an operation that takes all employees at once instead of one at a time? It could send back a response with the result of each employee. It would be more efficient than calling it multiple times.

Comment: @Crowcoder i have no access to the service to support collection of employees in POST request so sending one at a time is the only option left. Is there any way i can make POST request on the list of employees concurrently using TASK and at the last use Task.WhenAll() if all are successful.

Comment: You can send the list of employees but api should  be able to add the list too. So you have to change the API at first. If it is under your control post it in your question

Comment: @Serge I don't have access to API codebase. updated in question also.

Comment: @ShaniBhati It the api support async?   api should return  async Task if it is a net api.

Comment: Yes you can use WhenAll() but you'll need to use the async versions of the RestClient operations

Comment: @Serge i am not sure about the implementation of the API. Is there any way i can send employees list size request parallelly without waiting for each other and than in the last can check if all request are successful or not instead of sending one request after the other.

Comment: Web requests are naturally async from the client perspective. It doesn't matter if the API internally uses async operations, you can start all the requests and then WaitAll.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I understand this , but  we will not gain very much  if  inside of API the code is syncronous.

Comment: @Serge yes it does because you can make calls asynchronously. The back end is of no concern to the client

Comment: @Crowcoder As I understand  in this case the next request will be waiting till the data will be created for the previous one. If code inside api doesn't start another request before the previous one is finished it doesn' t save much time.

Comment: @Serge the API will start another request, that's how they work. If an API could only handle one request at a time it would not be very useful

Comment: Have you tried using the `Parallel.ForEach` method, or the PLINQ library?